# AWS Guidance using Cloudfront S3 for Static assets - EC2 for API calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to get my static website to send some very basic API calls to an EC2 instance - would anyone be able to share best practices or point me in the right direction?

Current setup is as follows:

- React bundle and static assets are served on cloudfront / s3
- SSL managed through ACM and automatically applied to my Cloudfront deployment
- Domain registered and managed through Route 53

It seems I have two options - pass the API calls through cloudfront (can't seem to get this to work) or allow cross origin client side and point my axios requests to a different IP. Is allowing CORS in this fashion considered bad practice?

For the first option, I have created a second origin on cloudfront and pointed it to a route 53 DNS which points to my elastic IP for ec2. Problem is, I can't get the API to work, despite enabling POST on all origins in my cloudfront console:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>MethodNotAllowed</Code>
<Message>The specified method is not allowed against this resource.</Message>
<Method>POST</Method>
<ResourceType>OBJECT</ResourceType>
<RequestId>2B5DB5E28188BE4A</RequestId>
<HostId>yXiiLTR5v8KERjzbG3fx4BGcZG5FO0e3Yufa0b9aC2W3sMyuOK3BBADtZj097T8E0qBZ3F/rBC8=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I guess my questions, aside from just sanity checking setup are as follows:

- Do I need to be running some sort of certificate on my EC2 instance? I am currently redirecting all HTTP to HTTPS for my static assets - how does this fit into making api calls with axios in React? Will api calls automatically be sent over 443 when the client is connected via https?
- Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm attempting to do? This is a personal website that has an email form (only reason it can't be completely static) - All I am running on the backend is an extremely lightweight node instance that sends emails to the owner

Thanks so much for your time and help! I appreciate it

Comment: You should consider using API Gateway https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/to manage the API concerns. At the same time, if your backend code is only for sending emails, you might consider using Lambda for that. It'll be cheaper, most likely free for your use case. And it's very easy to tie to Lambda. There are lots of guides for sending email from a JS Lambda function, like this one: https://www.scrivito.com/using-an-aws-lambda-function-to-send-an-email-after-form-submission-f0e6697e59a381ba

Comment: This is great. Yeah it seems silly to be running an entire node container just to handle this stuff - it's probably worth it to learn how to use Lambda functions. I'll take a look!

Comment: I suspect you are not showing the entire XML error.  Does it also have a `<RequestId>` and `<HostId>`?

Comment: Yes! I constructed a lambda function that does the same thing and integrated with API gateway as described above - but I'm getting the same error. I have updated my original post with the full message. Thanks for your help!

To be clear, at this point my endpoint works when I contact the API Gateway address directly, but using cloudfront and adding it as an origin does not. Any insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to make this setup work with CloudFront CDN - using lambda functions was the best approach. Create a Lambda function that processes each request and manage with AWS API Gateway.

CORS must be enabled on your S3 bucket using the following code snippet:

```
`<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
  <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>`
```

Also, something I took away from this exercise that might help other people: you need to return a 200 with these headers whenever a client sends an OPTIONS request to your endpoint. This can be done on any backend you choose, but here's a guide for API Gateway:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Here's a guide I found that describes how to create a similar (highly scalable) stack:

https://www.codeengine.com/articles/process-form-aws-api-gateway-lambda/

Thanks!